# T-SQL - subqueries on rows grouped by ID to create a summary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table "MyTable" with an id and two int fields "A" and "B":

```
MyTable
+-------+-----+-----+
|   ID  |  A  |  B  |
+-------+-----+-----+
|    99 |  0  |  1  |
|    99 |  0  |  1  |
|    99 |  0  |  0  |
|    99 |  1  |  1  |
|    99 |  0  |  1  |
|   100 |  1  |  0  |
|   100 |  0  |  0  |
|   100 |  0  |  0  |
|   444 |  1  |  0  |
|    88 |  0  |  0  |
|    88 |  0  |  0  |
|    88 |  0  |  1  |
+-------+-----+-----+
```

I'd like a T-SQL query to return a single row for each distinct id, which contains:

each distinct ID
whether there exists a row for that ID with a non-zero value for "a"
whether there exists a row for that ID with a non-zero value for "b"

like so:

```
+-------+-----+-----+
|   ID  |  A  |  B  |
+-------+-----+-----+
|    99 |  1  |  1  |
|   100 |  1  |  0  |
|   444 |  1  |  0  |
|    88 |  0  |  1  |
+-------+-----+-----+
```

I can GROUP BY the ID, but I don't know how to create the joins or subqueries on each group to get the desired result.

Comment: Just do a group by id and select max(a),max(b)

Comment: Or, just to use [`Sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), if the values are always non-negative and may be `>1`: `Sign( Max( A ) ) as A, Sign( Max( B ) ) as B`. Negative values may be handled with `Sign( Max( Abs( A ) ) ) as A, Sign( Max( Abs( B ) ) ) as B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, max(case when A<>0 then 1 else 0 end)A, max(case when B<>0 then 1 else 0 end)B
from mytable 
group by id
```

Or you can just use since your value is 1 and 0. But if value is other than that please use first query.

```
select id, max(A)A, max(B)B
from mytable 
group by id
```